# How to read the search results by the Search Rest Api XML

Tags: search, rest

When I enter the url below for Search Rest Api I can see some xml on the browser. Is there some tool or something else to read this xml? I would like to know which results are found.

```
http://internet-manage.mycompany.com/_api/search/query?QueryTemplatePropertiesUrl='spfile://webroot/queryparameters.xml'&selectproperties='Title,HitHighlightedSummary,Path'&properties='SourceName:Internet%20Result%20Source'&rowlimit=5&cultureid=1043&querytext='(paris)'
```

Answer (score 2):

[SharePoint 2013 Search Query Tool](https://sp2013searchtool.codeplex.com/) from Codeplex is a very nice tool for testing / interacting with the SharePoint search api.

Comment: Very good tool, helps reading results and crafting queries.

Comment: I already install it, but I cannot enter my own rest api url somewhere.

Comment: On the left pane in the tool there is a grouped section called `Connection`. After you've expanded it you can enter your own Site Url, Timeout, Authentication, etc.

Comment: I think you can enter there only the site url and not the whole rest api url like in my example.

Comment: Ah. Now I got it. Maybe you should ask that specific question (if you can manually enter your whole custom rest url) in the `Discussion` section of the Codeplex site of the tool at: https://sp2013searchtool.codeplex.com/discussions

Comment: I was wondering if there are known solutions to read the xml. Maybe there are other tools??

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "read the xml"? Some sort of "beautification", e.g. display the results in a grid?

Comment: yes, thats what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that this question is more about exploring REST data rather then SharePoint Search REST results, here is the list of tools (browser extensions) I usually prefer for that purpose:

- [Postman - REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm) (*Chrome extension*)
  [image]
- [DHC - REST/HTTP API Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhc-resthttp-api-client/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm) (*Chrome extension*)
  [image]
- [RESTClient, a debugger for RESTful web services](https://addons.mozilla.org/fi/firefox/addon/restclient/) (Firefox extension)